# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ruamel (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for ruamel

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

here is the python version:

```
Python 3.6.5
```

and I want to install ruamel with:

```
pip3 install ruamel
```

but I can't install it:

```
(venvpython3) d3alg@ubuntu-59:/$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
(venvpython3) d3alg@ubuntu-59:/$ pip3 install ruamel
Collecting ruamel
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ruamel (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ruamel
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The command to install might be "pip install ruamel.yaml" as it's mentioned here: https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/

Answer (score 3):

If you search [`PyPI`](https://pypi.org/) for [`ruamel`](https://pypi.org/search/?q=ruamel), you'll see that there is no package with that name. All available packages have that string as a namespace (`ruamel.`). You actually have to select each package you want to install (although some will depend on others and pull in multiple "`ruamel.`" namespaced packages):

```
pip3 install -y ruamel.yaml
```